# Where does Mac OS X store the file associations (per file)

Tags: macos, mac, file-association

When I open a file info, and change the application responsible for that file, where is this override stored on the system?

Answer (score 4):

The data is stored in the resource fork of the file, which is stored as the extended attribute `com.apple.ResourceFork`.

Take the following as an example -

Using **Terminal**, create a test file, calling it "test.txt"

```
System:~ user$ touch test.txt
```

By default "txt" extension files are opened with **TextEdit**. (Unless you've modified the system-wide default.) In the **Finder**, change the association to something else. Go back to the **Terminal** ..

```
 System:~ user$ ls -l@ test.txt

 -rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  0 Sep 29 11:21 test.txt
         com.apple.ResourceFork 1338
```

The `@` symbol denotes the file has extended attributes, and `ls -l@` lists the attributes as part of the long format.

If you have the Developer Tools installed, you can use `DeRez` to inspect the resource fork, and you'll see the path of the application you selected in the fork.

It's archaic, deprecated, and could (rightly) be called a hack ... but given that the UTI and bundle identifier system is "incomplete", it's what Apple uses.

Comment: Where's @ documented? Current (10.7.4) OS X Darwin `ls` supports the following options. `ls -ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1`

Comment: @slomojo - According to Apple's [online man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/ls.1.html) for `ls` for 10.7.4, @ is still accepted.

Comment: Thanks, seem they just overlooked it on the quick opt list, and I happened to try it out on a folder containing only files that didn't have res-forks. - It's working (no surprise) in ML 10.8 too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Mac OS X, but Mac OS (i.e. Classic) used to store this in the resource fork of each file with two pieces of information: the type code and the creator code. Both were four-byte sequences and were thus usually rendered as four character strings. The [type code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_code) identified the type of the file (e.g. TEXT for a text file, APPL for an application), while the [creator code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creator_code) identifies the application that created the file (e.g. ttxt for SimpleText or MSWD for Microsoft Word). Thus a file created by SimpleText would open in SimpleText by default, while still being identified as a text file and therefore compatible with Microsoft Word, should you choose to manually open it with Word.

Snow Leopard no longer pays any attention to type and creator codes, having replaced them with [UTIs](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/09/09/22/inside_snow_leopards_uti_apple_fixes_the_creator_code.html), which are reminiscent of MIME types, although more flexible, and can be used to specify the default program as well as determining which programs are compatible with a given file, but I'm not sure how individual overrides are done.

Comment: Changes are stored in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist Mac OS X also stores more information in /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist & ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist & ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.plist However, I was unable to locate where the global overrides are stored.